# Connecting a Wireless laptop to a network printer

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, printer, lan

I have the following situation.
I have a laptop with WIN10 connected wirelessly to a netgear R6700 router. This router is then connected to a Cisco RV345 which is the brains for my entire home network. To the Cisco router I also have connected a LAN printer MFP M479fdn to which all LAN computers print to.
Now I would like to also print from the wirelessly connected laptop.
The printer has an ip 192.168.3.100 while the laptop has 192.168.100.6 for example. The IP for the laptop is dhcp-ed from netgear.
I was able to install the printer driver on the laptop after providing the 192.168.3.100 ip address. The installation exited successfully however when I go to see the printers installed on my Laptop it shows my printer as being offline. Any prints I sent to it get stuck in the queue.
Is there any configuration I need to make to the netgear or cisco router? I already have intervlan enabled on Cisco.
One more thing to mention I can open a web page on the laptop and can see the printer setting by entering the ip of the printer. Also pinging the printer from the laptop is successful, however the printer still showing as OFFLINE.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a laptop with WIN10 connected wirelessly to a netgear R6700
> router. This router is then connected to a Cisco RV345

I have the same central router here, an HP Printer and two wireless computers. Every device (including iPhones) can print.

Connect the Netgear router as follows:

**1. LAN port on Netgear router to LAN port on RV345.**

(LAN port for VLAN 1). The VLAN table / settings in the RV345 has this information. You may be able to use an untagged port that is part of the main network (so that the Netgear appears like the main network).

**2. Give the Netgear router a static IP** on the main network.

**3. Turn DHCP OFF on the Network Router.**

You may need to turn Wireless Isolation OFF on the Netgear Router - check for that setting.

Restart both routers.

Now all devices are on one subnet and you can print.

You should reset the wireless Printer to the same subnet. It is worth giving the Printer a static IP on the network so it does not get lost when you restart the network.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I cannot implement that. The reason is Cisco router is configured with multiple VLANs. Each of my kids are on separate VLANs my network and servers are on others, the printer on another and the netgear wireless router on another. Also the netgear wireless router cannot have the dhcp disabled since it connects multiple smart devices to the internet.
I hope there is another way to tackle this problem while the laptop and the printer remain on separate subnets.

Comment: VLANs might require additional printers OR, keep all people on one VLAN.   I do the latter because I do not want a proliferation of printers. You have to accept the path of least resistance to you..

Comment: The thing is all lan computers can already print to the same printer even though all of them are on separate vlans. Is just this wireless laptop which cannot print.

Comment: If all LAN computers can print, then connect the wireless router as shown in the answer to a port on the RV345 that will work for this.

Comment: You might also experiment with an untagged port so the Netgear appears to the main network .

Comment: Each port that belong to each VLAN is already Untagged.

Comment: The crazy thing is I can ping the printer from the laptop and also the laptop can access the web settings of the printer in chrome, showing "Connected".
Is just Windows10 who cannot see the printer after it installed the driver and connected to it.

Comment: Just use a port that the whole network can see. Your printer (you said) is wireless where the RV345 is only wired so the printer must be getting wireless from the Netgear. Keep that in mind as hooking up .  You should be able to establish a main IP address for the Netgear. It sounds to me to be very complicated where it may not need to be.

Comment: Maybe set up your main Router, then the Netgear, make it work, then make the subsidiary VLANs from the result.  Also make VERY sure if your ISP's Modem has wireless either (a) turn it off and use the netgear or (b) leave it on do not use the netgear

Comment: The printer is wired to the LAN, the only thing wireless is the laptop and netgear which is also on the LAN provides the wireless connection for the laptop.

Comment: You need to edit the question because you said the printer was wireless.  So hook up the netgear to a similar port as the wired printer.  Like I suggested - simplify this ( for your own ease of management.). The netgear needs to be connected with a LAN port not the WAN port.